# How to specify the output format for Null node in yaml-cpp?

Tags: yaml-cpp

I use current(2013/12/12) latest revision of yaml-cpp.

I noticed that both `YAML::Load("")`
and `YAML::Load("---\n...")` results in a Null node,
i.e. `YAML::Load("").Type() == YAML::NodeType::Null`
yet when sent to `std::ostream` the former outputs an empty string
but the latter outputs tilde (`~`).

I want both nodes to output an empty string.
How can I achieve it?

I want to do so because I noticed tilde is interpreted as a string when I use `YAML::Load`.

Here is the code to show this difference.

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    YAML::Node node1 = YAML::Load("");
    YAML::Node node2 = YAML::Load("---\n...");

    assert (node1.Type() == YAML::NodeType::Null);
    assert (node2.Type() == YAML::NodeType::Null);

    std::cout << node1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << node2 << std::endl;
}

/* OUTPUT:

~
*/
```

Comment: This can't be done in yaml-cpp now. Could you please file a bug report on the project page?

Comment: @JesseBeder I filed the [issue 230](https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=230).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Github Issue](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/issues/230), this behavior was fixed in 2016.